# How to remove the MATLAB error '...file is being used by another process '?

Tags: matlab, video-processing, video-compression

I am doing a project on video-compression on MATLAB.

Part of my code is:

```
videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader('myVideo.avi');
videoFWriter = vision.VideoFileWriter('myVideo.avi','AudioInputPort',true);
videoFrame = step(videoFReader);
step(videoFWriter,videoFrame,audioData);
release(videoFReader);
release(videoFWriter);
```

and I get the error:

> Error using VideoFileWriter/step
>
> Could not start the filter graph : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
>
> Error in project_code (line 129)
>
> ```
>  step(videoFWriter,videoFrame,audioData);
> ```

I can't figure out a way to remove this error. Help please!

Comment: The error message tells the problem clearly. That file is already opened in MATLAB or in some other application. Close that file before proceeding.

Comment: Why would you read and write from the same file??? Of course you can't open the same file twice. What did you expect would happen, what do you want to accomplish?